Error method PUT HTTPS IIS 10 Angular 16 Windows Server 2019
I have a Web Site (Angular 16). That's deploy in IIS 10 (HTTPS port 443 with a Certificate)
I have ARR enabled, and on my web site tengo a rewrite ruler.
My back-end is in Node.js. It's running in the same serv but in other port (3000), also with HTTPS and a Certificate.
No problem when call back-end para method POST. Is OK no problem.
The problem is when the web call a PUT method. Never reaches my back-end. I know that because I have the next code beginning my server.js (archivo principal in my back-end):
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(`Ruta recibida: ${req.url}`);
  next();
});

Never reaches the PUT to my back-end because not print nada.
In the console Chrome. Say that: PUT rutacompleta 403 (Forbidden)
When I call the same PUT method with POSTMAN no problem, works OK. But the problem is when I use Chrome, I can't.
service code:
InactivarUsuario(
  usuario: Usuario,
  token: string
): Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {
  const url = `${configGlobal.urlApiTerrenos}usuarios/actualizaestadovigenciausuario`;
  const headers = new HttpHeaders({
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`, // Añade el token en el encabezado de autorización
  });
  return this.http.put<any>(
    url,
    { usuario },
    { headers, observe: 'response' }
  );
}

component.ts code:
if (this.token) {
  this.usuarioService
    .InactivarUsuario(usuario, this.token)
    .pipe(
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (error.status === 0) {
          this.messageConfirmationModal =
            'Problemas de Red, por favor, comunicarse con personal de TI';
        }
        return of(null);
      })
    )
    .subscribe((data) => {
      if (data && data.status === 200) {
        if (usuario.vigencia === 'A') {
          this.toastr.success('El usuario ha sido activado con éxito.'); // Muestra el toast
        } else {
          this.toastr.success('El usuario ha sido inactivado con éxito.'); // Muestra el toast
        }

        this.buscarUsuarios();
      }
    });
}


please share the service method and component code used to make this API call

@angular service method:
InactivarUsuario(usuario: Usuario, token: string): Observable<HttpResponse>{
const url = ${configGlobal.urlApiTerrenos}usuarios/actualizaestadovigenciausuario;
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}` // Añade el token en el encabezado de autorización
    });

    return this.http.put<any>(url, { usuario } ,{headers, observe:'response'});
}


component code also, please update on the question, the code which uses this service method

ok. Component code ok the update in the question

your code looks fine stackblitz so you are either not calling the method, check your chrome debugger network tab and check if the API is called, else validate the URL in the network tab is correct.

I have the problem only with de PUT Api, I don't have problem with POST Api. The console of Chrome says: 403 Forbidden. I have enable ARR in my ISS and I have a rule of rewrite. All is ok with POST but only put have problem. The problem is a level of IIS I supose that bacause when I call with postman or cmd my PUT Api no problem.

the server understands your request but does not accept it, because the payload you are sending does not match the specs of the API, according to the error. could you please share the API code, since frontend issues are ruled out.

@NarenMurali I have a quetion:
In my service code I have this parameter
usuario: Usuario
This parameter arrive in my service code with a lot of properties.
My method in mi node app does not need all the properties only need 3:
const { usuario } = req.body;

Is posible a error that? I don't believe that is that the error because I know I pass the 3 properites in variable usuario (and other properties but the three of the method are correct)

extra properties are ok, but what is required by the API must be present, else 403 fires

I have this code inmediatly next to the require list in my principal archive of my proyect in node:
app.use((req, res, next) => {
console.log(Ruta recibida: ${req.url});  // Esto te mostrará si la ruta reescrita está llegando correctamente
next();
});
I never see in console the message when I connect with Chrome (I press the button of my web that connect to the API) but if I use postman no problem I see the console.log and the method complete. The column in the database are update.

check if setting the same http headers as postman solves the issue, in postman, you can get the code version of the API call on the the right side if I remember correctly.

What is the error sub-status code? You can refer to this document to check if it matches your situation.

@XudongPeng hi, I prefered yesterdey change the method to post. I analized the situation and get a conclution. I Don't Know if I'm right but I thin yes. Check the Sittuation. I have enable the features Aplication Request Routing (ARR) in the IIS and on the specific web site I have one rule of URL Re Write. That rule work catch the word "api" and rewrite the url, change to other server on port 3000 (pm2 my back-end in node) I don't have proble with post, but with put I have problem because I supose the logic of IIS is check the permision before change the url write, and the carpet is not exist
